# What is the class name in Unity's AddComponent?

Tags: unity, c#, scripting

Unity's [AddComponent()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) method has an optional parameter of a `string`.  This `string` is the `className`.  What is the class name?  What is it used for?  I could not find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the class name of the component you want to add. For example, if you created a MonoBehaviour script named `GoToPosition` and wanted to add it to a game object via script you would call: `AddComponent("GoToPosition");`

That being said, this isn't typically a method I use. I'd rather be explicit about it and use the alternate method of adding components: `AddComponent<GoToPosition>()`. This ensures a few things:

1. It's strongly typed, so I know if I spelled the component name correctly.
2. If I change the name of the component, I can confirm the name changes everywhere (doesn't work as well when the name is a string)

Now, *that* being said. The text version does have advantages. I've used it when creating a system for externally scripting entities. In that case, I can just add the names of the components I want to add to an entity in an external text file. Then I can use the text version of `AddComponent` to easily add the components to entities when parsing the external text file. It's kind of a shortcut for using reflection to find the component class myself.

Both have their uses, but in most cases, you should use the generic type method `AddComponent<GoToPosition>()`.

Comment: These are the moments I wish Unity supported C#6 with typesafe `nameof()` operator giving you best of both worlds.

Comment: @wondra Apparently, you can use C#6: http://dev.cafe/using-c-6-0-with-unity-and-net-framework-3-5-part-1/, with a bit of work.

Answer (score 4):

It appears to just be the *name of the type* of component, used to look up which actual object to create or which component to get (later, when you called `GetComponent`).

The string versions of these functions exist, presumably, for untyped languages that could not use `Type` (inferred from a generic parameter) like C# can.